# jQuery cant access element with its attr href // simple tabs structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, selector, href

I can't access "a" element with its href. Like this example, i need add class to element which got href="#one"

[***Here is jsFiddle.***](http://jsfiddle.net/4Mhcr/18/)

**jQuery:**

```
//tabs part is working fine
$('.tabs').hide();
$('.tabs:first').show();
$('ul li a').click(function(){
   var target = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.tabs').hide();
    $(target).fadeIn(500);

   $('ul li a').removeClass('selected');
   $(this).addClass('selected');
});

   //problem starts when i try to reach href
   var link1 = '#one';
   var link2 = '#two';
   var link3 = '#three';

   var takE = $('ul li a').each();
   var finD = take.attr('href');
   finD.addClass('thisisLink1');​
```

**html:**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#one">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#two">Posts</a></li>
    <li><a href="#three">About</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tabs" id="one">Home Container</div>
<div class="tabs" id="two">Posts Container</div>
<div class="tabs" id="three">About Container</div>​
```

I have tried each method but it didn't work. I need to access elements with their attr href and set the object to addClass or animate. This way returns me as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('ul li a').each(function() {
  if(this.href == link1) $(this).addClass('thisisLink1');
  if(this.href == link2) $(this).addClass('thisisLink2');
  if(this.href == link3) $(this).addClass('thisisLink3');
});
```

You can also use an object mapping:

```
 var links = {
    '#one': 'thisislink1',
    '#two': 'thisislink2',
    '#three': 'thisislink3',
};
$.each(links, function(key, val) {
    $('ul li a[href="' + key + '"]').addClass(val);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jFZyZ/15/)**

Comment: $('ul li a[href="' + key + '"]') this part may work, i am trying atm

Comment: yeah object mapping method works fine mate, thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Use attribute selector like so:

```
$('a[href="#one"]').addClass(...)
```

Also note that you defined a `takE` variable and the you wrote `take`: probably you may want to write

```
   var takE = $('ul li'),
       finD = takE.find('a[href="#one"]');

   finD.addClass('thisisLink1');
```

Comment: i am writing a plugin and need to set that as a variable. like var link1 = '#one';
$('a[href=link1]').addClass(...)

Comment: ('a[href="#one"]') can i set "#one" part as an variable ?