# hide href element in specific UL with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, href

How we can hide href element in specific UL element ( not in all UL elements, because UL elements are with the same name).

For example we have HTML code like this:

```
<ul class="UL_tag">
  <li>Text 1</li>
  <li>Text 2</li> 
  <li><a href="http://www.google.com" class="description">Link to GOOGLE</a></li>
</ul>   

<ul class="UL_tag">
  <li>Text 1</li>
  <li>Text 2</li> 
  <li><a href="http://www.yahoo.com" class="description">Link to Yahoo</a></li>
</ul>
```

And we can hide these href's by using this code:

```
$('a.description').hide();
```

How should I change this javascript code, if I want to hide just one href element which is in the one UL element? Not all href elements with the class name "description" ?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: which one you want to hide..... Use eq(0) or :first-child jquary

Comment: What is unique about the `ul` in question?

Comment: How do you identify which element to hide? Why show one, and not the other? And, incidentally, those are `a` elements with an `href` *attribute*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can traverse the dom to get the element within the parent ul

```
$(this).parent().siblings().find('a.description').hide();
// get current clicked > parent li > siblings > find a.description in li siblings > hide
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CjfXu/1/

**EDIT**

Since your li is actually wrapped inside a span also.. .parent won't work as it's getting the span element.  You need to use .closest() - which gets the closest ancestor that matches

```
$(this).closest('li').siblings().find('.description').hide();
```

Also don't bind a click event inside another click event as that causes the dom to attach multiple event handlers to the element.  Always bind inside the document.ready function.  Dynamically created elements or when you have many elements that you need to bind, using delegation would be the most efficient way.

You had your code like this

```
$('a.start').bind('click', function(){ // <-- this should be $('a:not(.start)').bind 
     // code

     $('a.start').click(function(e) {            
         $(this).parent().siblings().find('.description').hide();
     });            

});
```

Which is binding any anchors with class=start a click event each time the first anchor is clicked

to use delegation

```
$('parentElement').on('click','element', function(){

})
```

or jQuery 1.6 and below

```
$('parentElement').delegate('element','click', function(){

});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This looks very promising, but somehow it doesn't work when I use my JavaScript code, which I posted above your post.

Comment: where are you adding this code?  don't add it after the `return false;` as it will never get to that part then

Comment: Best way would be to make your own fiddle and replicate your issue.  that way I see what you are seeing

Comment: I think that this is not working because I try to use 'click' two times:

$('a.start').bind('click', function(){

and there also:

$('a.start').click(function( e){

Is there a way to change these somehow? I think these two can't work together. Thank your for your answer!

Comment: your first one you should use ​`$('a:not(.start)').bind('click'`  http://jsfiddle.net/4Rtq8/

Comment: If I use this, my start class isn't working anymore when I click on the button. 

The weirdest thing is that everything is working with your code on jsfiddle. I add my all JS code and everything on jsfiddle is still working, but this is not working on my web page.

Comment: Is your page live?  can i get a link to see it directly?  or if you can - recreate the issue on jsfiddle and I can help take a look

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. You can take a look at the main idea at this link: http://jsfiddle.net/CjfXu/10/ , there is all the main code.

As you can see , when you press the "start" button, "description" will not disappear! 

There is a few more js files. (for interactive menu as you can see)

Comment: it's because you have that extra span wrapped around which .parent() only goes up one level.  this is what you need `$(this).closest('li').siblings().find('.description').hide();` http://jsfiddle.net/CjfXu/12/

Comment: @jomajo  I also moved your `$('a').click` function outside of your first.   You are binding a new click event everytime you click the first one.  You only have to bind it once unless you are adding the elements dynamically then you would have to use delegation

Comment: That's really nice. Everything is working as I want! Thank you very much Wirey!!!

Comment: As I can't find any more info how to talk directly to you, could you join #lwjgl IRC channel or write me an email? 

thank you very much for your help again!

Answer (score 2):

You can use attr href selector:

```
$('a[href="http://www.yahoo.com"]').hide();
```

Here is an example links, which you can use with different methods:

- http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/
- http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/

And this questions also related: [jQuery cant access element with its attr href // simple tabs structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11048770/jquery-tabs-cant-access-element-with-its-href)

Comment: This would hide any other link to yahoo [if any in the page] - just narrow it to `.UL_tag`^^

Answer (score 0):

You should give proper `id`s to each `<ul>`:

```
<ul class="UL_tag" id="firstList">
  <li>Text 1</li>
  <li>Text 2</li> 
  <li><a href="http://www.google.com" class="description">Link to GOOGLE</a></li>
</ul>   

<ul class="UL_tag" id="secondList">
  <li>Text 1</li>
  <li>Text 2</li> 
  <li><a href="http://www.yahoo.com" class="description">Link to Yahoo</a></li>
</ul>
```

And then:

```
$('#firstList a.description').hide();
```

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev, `#firstList` will hide `ul` and `#fisrstList a.description` will hide the `a` which is child of `ul`

Answer (score 0):

select the element by tagname and class, and then filter for href value:

```
$('a.description[href="http://www.google.com"]').hide();
```

you can also limit the result to only elements inside the class `.UL_tag`:

```
$('a.description[href="http://www.google.com"]', '.UL_tag').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML :**

```
<ul class="UL_tag">
  <li>Text 1</li>
  <li>Text 2</li>
  <li><a href="http://www.google.com" class="description">Link to GOOGLE</a></li>
</ul>   

<ul class="UL_tag">
  <li>Text 1</li>
  <li>Text 2</li>
  <li><a href="http://www.yahoo.com" class="description">Link to Yahoo</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Jquery:**

```
 var d = $('.UL_tag li').children('a')[1]; // If you remove first href element  change it to value "1" to "0"
 $(d).hide();
```

**See this Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/7aNRZ/8/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers, I think all of these answers are also correct answers, but what I'm trying to achieve is a bit different. Actually there is 3 li elements (two of them are with href tag):

```
 <ul class="UL_tag"> 
   <li>There you can download something.</li> 
   <li><a href="rapidshare.com/file.zip"; class="start">Download</a></li> 
   <li><a href="google.com"; class="description">Link to GOOGLE</a></li> 
</ul>
```

When you click on the "Download" link, javascript will be called:

```
$(function(){
    var seconds = 10;
    var canClick = true;
    seconds *= 1000;

    $('a.start').bind('click', function(){
      if(canClick){
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        var loader = $('input[name="link"]').val();

        $(this).html('<img src="' + loader + '"/>');
        setInterval(function(){
            window.location.reload();
            window.location = link; 
        }, seconds);
        // Description will be hidden everywhere.
        // How we can hide description in only one
        // row. In row where the a.start was called?
        $('a.description').hide();

        canClick = false;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

It will show the "loading gif" and after 10seconds user will beredirect to the download page.

So is it possible to hide "description" in only one row not everywhere. Just in a row where we call this "start" function?

The biggest problem is to hide just one li element, when all UL's and li's have same class name.